I want to lay new carpet and install a wall but I don't know what order I should do this in
I want to replace the existing carpet on the lower level of our house with new carpet but I also want to section off part the room for a new bed room. Should I tear up the old carpet, install the wall and then lay the new carpet or should I lay new carpet first and then install the wall?
Thanks

New wall usually means new paint.  Paint on carpet not good.  Carpet usually goes to walls.  Carpet under walls is weird and if it gets wet, usually need to remove wall.  Carpets are done last.

Never carpet under a wall. That’s just structurally wrong.

Since building a wall to section off part of your basement will in all probability include a lot of mess and dust, I'd highly recommend tearing out the old carpet, doing all your construction, then after everything else is done and cleaned up, installing the new carpet.  Construction debris can be very hard on carpets, either old or new.  In addition, if you put in the new carpet before building the new wall, you very likely might be off slightly on measurements and it won't look good or you'll have gaps.

IMO, it really depends on the timeline.  If the OP is certain to get new carpet done ASAP after completing the wall, ripping out all the carpet at once and doing the wall is OK.  But if there may be some lag between the wall and carpet replacement, I'd actually recommend removing the carpet only where the wall will go.  The adjacent carpet can be covered during wall construction.  And even if some dirt gets into the carpet, it's going away soon anyway.  Although the OP isn't really that specific about the carpet replacement timeline.
